# Is it possible to capture the load percentage of content being downloaded in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a section on my site where I display user uploads. Currently, I do this via an iFrame like this:

```
<iframe src="path/to/users/file.pdf" width="500px" height="500px"  />
```

Some of these files can be huge, so I'd like to show a progress bar so users can track what's going on.

I found a ton of answers on SO relating to checking when the content of an iframe itself is 100% loaded (so that a spinner can be disabled). However, I want to show the actual percentage of what has been downloaded.

Is this possible?

If it can't be done that way, can I "inject" raw data onto the page somehow? For instance, if I make an `ajax` call to `/path/to/filedownload.pdf', can I pop that response onto the page?

I'm not totally sure where to start with this.

Comment: if you use AJAX you'll be able to create a data URI after it loads. For resources like PDFs this may cause some clients to attempt to download the resource rather than embed it.

Comment: You can use a library that does that already, something like http://createjs.com/PreloadJS

Comment: This is doable, but not neccessarely easy to do from scratch. Most serverside languages have a way to get the uploaded amount of bytes, total amount of bytes etc. and then you'd generally use ajax to poll a serverside script that tells how must is sent etc.